# Is There Aspect Ratio Cropping in CQ5, Not Just Free Crop?

Tags: image, aspect-ratio, aem

The image component allows Free Ratio cropping out of the box. I'm a bit baffled at why there is no Aspect Ratio option (keeping height and width constrained to each other), which would work much better for us. Is this an existing feature that can be enabled, or a custom task in Java?

I am using CQ 5.4.

[image]

Comment: You didn't ask this question, but... It's a good idea to manage crops back in the DAM, or wherever you have stored the images.  The crop that author X prepares for one page is probably the same crop that author Y would like to use on another.

Comment: You do make an excellent point. But I will keep it on the side burner until I can get this issue resolved first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to generate images with different aspectRatios, try this...

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2013/09/cq-image-custom-aspect-ratios-crop.html

The crop parameters are saved in different properties and not "cropParameter" of the html5smartimage widget

Answer (score 3):

This is OOTB since 5.4 (atleast), though not well documented.. Set up your smart image widget like so:

```
<image-16x10
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    allowFileReference="{Boolean}true"
    cropParameter="./image-16x10/imageCrop"
    fileReferenceParameter="fileReference"
    name="./image-16x10/file"
    requestSuffix=".img.png"
    rotateParameter=""
    title="16x10"
    xtype="html5smartimage">
    <cropConfig
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <aspectRatios
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <aspectRatio-16x10
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="16x10"
                    value="16,10"/>
        </aspectRatios>
    </cropConfig>
</image-16x10>
```

The `cropConfig` node structure is what youre interested in. text="16x:10" is what will appear in the Crop dropdown, value="16,10" is the actual fixed Crop size for the tool. You can add as many predefined crops you want per `html5smartimage` widget.

The `image-16x10` and `aspectRatio-16x10` names aren't required, but not a useful convention to help in maintainability of the config.If you allow multiple aspectRatios then the `image-16x10` naming probably doesnt make as much sense tho its not a bad idea to provide semantic naming to your aspectRatio definition node.

Comment: So I am creating a custom widget that uses the same superResource as above, but allows me to add in my own cropping constraints?

Comment: For what component you want Images added to with the fixed crop dimensions, add the cropConfig/* node config to that component's html5smart image cq:Widget node. The above is just a widget definition so it doesnt have a resourceSuperType/resourceType. Your component might have a resourceSuperType of foundation/component/image if you are overlaying the Image component to have fixed crop ratios (in that case you wouldnt want to be saving to ./image-16x10/* though)

Answer (score 0):

That would be a custom JavaScript widget: the one you're using ([smart image](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.SmartImage)) does not have an aspect ratio functionality (or just I never seen one), even in 5.6.

You could extend the existing widget, and provide this functionality in your own, using Javascript though -- it's not trivial, but not rocket science either -- see source code for smart image to see how it extends smart panel, and then registers itself into the framework.

Comment: would extending the widget require extJS coding, or regular old Javascript?

Comment: That's ExtJs for you, but effectively you don't need much more than extending class and registering new xtype.